# Extender controlador de un Symfony 4 Bundle externo a una vista diferente

Tags: php, php7, symfony, symfony4

Tengo un Bundle externo que renderiza vistas básicas y hay la necesidad de mejorarlas. Existe una manera de reutilizar los controladores cambiando unicamente la vista sin tener que literalmente copiarlos y pegarlos? algo así como un extend, quiero reutilizar la lógica y las variables cambiando solamente la vista.

Tengo estos dos controladores

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->  <?php
# Metodo de Controlador dentro de un Bundle externo en /vendor/{vendor-name}/front-core-bundle/src/FrontCoreBundle/Controller/NameController.php
public function homeAction()
        {
            $vamsUtilsPurchase = $this->get('front_core.vams.utils.purchase');
            $vamsSDK = $this->get('front_core.vams_sdk');
            $notificator = $this->get('front_core.notificator.flash');
            $translator = $this->get('front_core.translator');
            $unitsSummary = $vamsSDK->getUsersModule()->getUserUnitsSummary($vamsUtilsPurchase->unitsType());
            $coupons = null;

            try {
                $coupons = $vamsSDK->getPurchasesModule()->getMyCoupons(1, 5, 0);
            } catch (\Throwable $t) {
                $notificator->error(
                    $translator->trans('vams.error_' . $t->getCode(), [], self::DEFAULT_TRANSLATION_ERROR)
                );
            }
            try {
                $purchasesResult = $vamsSDK->getPurchasesModule()->getMyPurchases(1, 4, 'withtracking');
            } catch (\Throwable $t) {
                $notificator->error(
                    $translator->trans('vams.error_' . $t->getCode(), [], self::DEFAULT_TRANSLATION_ERROR)
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw $e;
            }

            $this->breadcrumb->appendItem('dashboard');

            return $this->render(
                '@FrontCore/template/private/home.html.twig',
                [
                    'summary' => $unitsSummary,
                    'purchases' => $purchasesResult['purchases'],
                    'coupons' => $coupons['coupons'],
                    'user' => $vamsSDK->getUsersModule()->me()->getFields(),
                    'check_voucher_form' => $this->createForm(CheckVoucherType::class)->createView(),
                ]
            );
        }
```

quiero usar el anterior de una manera similar a esta:

```
    <!-- language: lang-php -->  <?php
    # Metodo de Controlador propio
    public function homeAction(){

            return $this->render('otravista.html.twig',
                        [
                            'summary' => $unitsSummary,
                            'purchases' => $purchasesResult['purchases'],
                            'coupons' => $coupons['coupons'],
                            'user' => $vamsSDK->getUsersModule()->me()->getFields(),
                            'check_voucher_form' => $this->createForm(CheckVoucherType::class)->createView(),
                        ]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Porqué no pasas al controlador 2 variables, una que sea la ruta de la plantilla que quieres cargar y la otra un *array* con los parámetros para la vita. Te quedaría algo así:

```html
<?php
public action homeAction(string $rute, array $params){
  // Resto de codigo
  return $this->render($route, $params);
}
```

Y por último asegúrate de que al llamar a ese método desde otro, pasas correctamente las variables.

Si lo dejas de esta manera, cuando llames a la función, puedes hacer un *retunr* de dicha función, ya que es está la que devuelve el render.

Comment: Tomando en cuenta que el primer controlador no lo puedo editar, hay manera de que hacer lo que tú dices? :O